# How to toggle ng-class in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

Now I want to toggle class with `ng-class`, but now I am stuck with tab which has sub `<a>`. Here is **Html**

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li ng-class="{active:isActive('/home')}"><a ui-sref='home'>Home</a>
    </li>
    <li ng-class="{active:isActive('/ebin'||'/reports')}" class="dropdown"><a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Expenses<span class="caret"></span></a>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a ui-sref='ebin'>My Expenses</a>
            </li>
            <li><a ui-sref='reports'>Expense Reports</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li ng-class="{active:isActive('/settings')}"><a ui-sref='settings' translate="SETTINGS">Settings</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**JS part:**

```
$scope.isActive = function(route) {
        return route === $location.path();
    }
```

The issue I have here is the `ng-class` only work for /home and /setting, but doesn't work for dropdown menu. any Idea?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the parameter you are passing "isActive('/ebin'||'/reports')". This is not a valid string.

What you could do is this:

```
   ng-class="{'active':isActive('/ebin'), 'active':isActive('/reports')}"
```

Comment: I did try your way, but when you change from ebin to reports or from reports to ebin, the active class will be gone.